# Emulating a ManyToManyField with multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, django

A Django `ManyToManyField` renders something like this in HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="answers" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" >Question 1, Answer 1</option>
    <option value="2">Question 1, Answer 2</option>
    <option value="3">Question 1, Answer 3</option>
    <option value="4">Question 2, Answer 1</option>
    <option value="5">Question 2, Answer 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I can select one item manually from the question 1 group, and one item from the question 2 group. When this is sent in a POST request, I get a POST array containing `answers = [1, 3]` or similar.

I want to get the same behavior from groups of radio buttons, as this is a problem better suited to radio buttons. For example, if I do the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend>
        <input name="answers" id="id_1" value="1" type="radio">
        <label for="id_1">Answer 1</label>
        <br>

        <input name="answers" id="id_2" value="2" type="radio">
        <label for="id_2">Answer 2</label>
        <br>

        <input name="answers" id="id_3" value="3" type="radio">
        <label for="id_3">Answer 3</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 2</legend>
        <input name="answers" id="id_4" value="4" type="radio">
        <label for="id_4">Answer 1</label>
        <br>
        <input name="answers" id="id_5" value="5" type="radio">
        <label for="id_5">Answer 2</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It doesn't actually let the user select more than one radio button at once. On the other hand, if I name the radio buttons `answers[0]` and `answers[1]`, in POST, it sends two separate entities with those names instead of sending a combined `answers`.

I ask because on the back-end, I have a Django `ManyToManyField` and a `ModelForm` with a custom widget, and I'm trying to save the data into a `ManyToManyField` from this custom widget without resorting to too much trickery on the back end, but I keep getting the error "Enter a list of values."

Edit: JavaScript is acceptable so long as it doesn't send the original data as well, as is Django inheritance/custom parsing.

Edit 2: Here is my widget for the ManyToManyField as it stands now.

```
{% if questions %}
    {% for question in questions %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{ question.question }}</legend>
            {% if question.options %}
                {% for option in question.options %}
                    <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" name="answers" id="id_{{ option.id }}" value="{{ option.id }}">
                    <label for="id_{{ option.id }}">{{ option.text }}</label>
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>No options for this question.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No questions in test.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i think you can try checkbox

Comment: If you can make that into a complete answer that is supported in Django 1.11.8, I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't actually let the user select more than one radio button at
>   once. On the other hand, if I name the radio buttons answers[0] and
>   answers[1], in POST, it sends two separate entities with those names
>   instead of sending a combined answers.

This doesn't fullfil your requirements, but atleast resolve one mystery. When you use `answers[]` as name, backend will recognize it as array and join all values into array. This is possible with any input type except single (radio/select).

And this is js solution you can use, but your situation shows that model you are using is not optimal for this case. Ofc course it can be solved hacky way like bellow, but you will always have to solve workarounds when you meet this code..

So my advice: change approach in backend

```js
document.getElementById('answers').onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit;
  let clone = this.cloneNode(true);
  let inputs = clone.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  let formData = new FormData(clone); // HTML5
  // dumb check for validity
  if (Array.from(formData.values()).length != clone.querySelectorAll('fieldset').length) {
   alert('Invalid form!')
   return false;
  }  
  for (let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    inputs[i].type = "checkbox";
    inputs[i].name = "answers[]";
  }
  // only for snippet
  formData = new FormData(clone);
  console.log(Array.from(formData.entries()));
  // commented in snippet
  //clone.submit(); 
}

/* This is cleaner submit by JS without reload
document.getElementById('answers').onsubmit = function(e) {
 let formData = new FormData(this); // HTML5
  let answers = Array.from(formData.values());
  // dumb check for validity
  if (answers.length != this.querySelectorAll('fieldset').length) {
   alert('Invalid form!')
   return false;
  }
  let newFormData = new FormData();
  newFormData.set('answers', answers);
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open(this.method || "POST", this.action || '/default/post/link');
 request.send(newFormData);
  return false;
}
*/
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="answers">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend>
        <input name="question_1" id="id_1" value="1" type="radio">
        <label for="id_1">Answer 1</label>
        <br>

        <input name="question_1" id="id_2" value="2" type="radio">
        <label for="id_2">Answer 2</label>
        <br>

        <input name="question_1" id="id_3" value="3" type="radio">
        <label for="id_3">Answer 3</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 2</legend>
        <input name="question_2" id="id_4" value="4" type="radio">
        <label for="id_4">Answer 1</label>
        <br>
        <input name="question_2" id="id_5" value="5" type="radio">
        <label for="id_5">Answer 2</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `answers[]` is a PHP specific thing, I tried, it doesn't work with Django. I'll try your Javascript solution when I get home today.

Comment: I'd be okay changing the approach if you tell me how. Right now I have a test table with questions, each multiple options (with questions as the fk) and a TestResult table with a test fk and a manytomany with answers.

Comment: I am focused to frontend so my knowledge of db models is very limitied. Maybe somebody else can give you right advice to that. But I already did some Q/A surveys and can say that never had to work with model like this.

Comment: It looks like giving them different names doesn't merge into the `ManyToManyField` on the back-end.

Comment: @Hameer Abbasi Javascript merge them into answers. First example (not commented): 1) user chooses radio buttons 2) user submit form 3) js prevent submit and create cloned form 4) in this cloned form js replace type to checkbox and name for answer[] (or answers - try both) 5) then js trigger submit of this clone

Comment: I see. Nice hack!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the radio buttons to checkboxes should allow you to select multiple values.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend>
        <input name="answers" id="id_1" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="id_1">Answer 1</label>
        <br>

        <input name="answers" id="id_2" value="2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="id_2">Answer 2</label>
        <br>

        <input name="answers" id="id_3" value="3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="id_3">Answer 3</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 2</legend>
        <input name="answers" id="id_4" value="4" type="checkbox">
        <label for="id_4">Answer 1</label>
        <br>
        <input name="answers" id="id_5" value="5" type="checkbox">
        <label for="id_5">Answer 2</label>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The HTTP POST generated by this form should be exactly the same as the example you gave above with the `select` tag.

Comment: Yes, but then I can select multiple for one answer as well. And it doesn't look like a radio button.